# Is there a way to lower CPU speed on a single process?

Tags: windows-7, cpu

I am trying to play an old game on a relatively new desktop. And the mouse scroll rate and game speed are way to fast even when set to the lowest in game.

I would like to try underclocking the cpu. I can't seem to change the priority of the process for the game.

In genera, is there a way to change the cpu speed limit on a given process in Windows 7?

Comment: I posted an answer about setting the priority, but it sounds like you already tried that. You're asking about changing the CPU speed for a process. This is physically impossible given that your processors have to execute other processes too. Perhaps you can set up [Virtual Box](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/overview/index.html) and create a VM image with much less resources and run the game inside of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many old games were CPU limited. When I got my Mac 8100/80av, my Ambrosia Software games flew.

For windows you can try things like processes throttling, but if they're really old, you could use DOSbox.

http://mion.faireal.net/BES/

http://threadmaster.tripod.com/

http://www.dosbox.com/

Other than that, you could also try running it in compatibility mode.

Comment: Ok. Let me try!